# Detect ViewWillAppear in flutter, call Api function every time widget loads

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to call Api function and I want to run it every time I launch the screen just like on resume in android and View Will Appear in iOS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dart doesn't have that functionality in it's [View life cycle](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-lifecycle-for-android-and-ios-developers-8f532307e0c7), but here they provide [dependency](https://pub.dev/packages/focus_detector) which will work for sure. For [reference](https://edsonbueno.com/2020/03/19/bringing-on-resume-view-did-appear-to-flutter/) you can also check here.